# Is there a problem to send Map<Id,String> to batch?

Tags: apex, batch, error

I'm trying to send Map to Batch From Queueable apex

```
    Map < Id, String > conList = Insert_Update_Contact(data.Students, countryMap, citiesMap);
    System.debug('conList -> ' + conList); //Have values!
    if (conList.size() > 0) {

     Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new StudentFileBatch(conList), 200);


    }
```

But I got an Error :

> system.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

I tried to do the following :

```
   Map<Id,String> tempMap= new Map<Id,String>();
        tempMap.put('0031l000008SsJr','Hello');
        if(conList.size()>0){

             Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new StudentFileBatch(tempMap), 200);


        }
```

Got the same Error.

Batch Side is not really relevant - It's not even call it.
The null pointer show on the executeBatch line..

Any Idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code for (at least the constructor of) your batch class? There's nothing to say you can't pass a map into a constructor of a batch class, so the detail is likely to be in the code of your batch class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send any type of serializable data in to a batchable class, including virtually any type of Map collection. If you try to send in "invalid" data, you'd get an error specific to that process, not a generic NullPointerExeption error. The problem **is** in the constructor of your batch class code.

You can prove it to yourself that the constructor is the problem by modifying your code slightly:

```
Map<Id,String> tempMap= new Map<Id,String>();
tempMap.put('0031l000008SsJr','Hello');
StudentFileBatch batch = new StudentFileBatch(tempMap);
Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(batch);
```

You should see an error on the line where you construct the StudentFileBatch, not the Database.executeBatch line.

Comment: oh, feel so stupid right now.
Thanks a lot!